# Why does Base.rsplit not invert the order (compared to Base.split) of the data in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying out [`Base.rsplit()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.rsplit) for the first time and I was surprised to see that the order of the data does not change when I use `split` vs `rsplit`. See this example:

```
julia> my_string = "Hello.World.This.Is.A.Test"
"Hello.World.This.Is.A.Test"

julia> a = split(my_string, ".")
6-element Vector{SubString{String}}:
 "Hello"
 "World"
 "This"
 "Is"
 "A"
 "Test"

julia> b = rsplit(my_string, ".")
6-element Vector{SubString{String}}:
 "Hello"
 "World"
 "This"
 "Is"
 "A"
 "Test"

julia> a == b
true
```

This is a bit counterintuitive given that `rsplit` says:

> Similar to split, but starting from the end of the string.

Comment: I'd expect the order to mostly matter when you provide a limit. And *maybe* in some corner cases with regexes or longer, non-common separators

Comment: Yeah, agreed on the limit part, but still seems odd that the order would not be reversed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsplit` just goes from the right side and the only practical difference is the `limit` parameter.

Try typing in Julia:

```
@less rsplit("txt",".")
```

You will find the following function:

```
function _rsplit(str::AbstractString, splitter, limit::Integer, keepempty::Bool, strs::Array)
    n = lastindex(str)::Int
    r = something(findlast(splitter, str)::Union{Nothing,Int,UnitRange{Int}}, 0)
    j, k = first(r), last(r)
    while j > 0 && k > 0 && length(strs) != limit-1
        (keepempty || k < n) && pushfirst!(strs, @inbounds SubString(str,nextind(str,k)::Int,n))
        n = prevind(str, j)::Int
        r = something(findprev(splitter,str,n)::Union{Nothing,Int,UnitRange{Int}}, 0)
        j, k = first(r), last(r)
    end
    (keepempty || n > 0) && pushfirst!(strs, SubString(str,1,n))
    return strs
end
```

Comment: I wonder if it makes sense to make the `limit` argument required since otherwise why would you use `rsplit`?

Comment: `rsplit` is twice as slow compared to `split` so maybe it should just fallback to `split` (perhaps with a warning) when no `limit` is given

Comment: But also: without the limit keyword why are you using it at all?

Comment: I agree `rsplit` is not needed when `limit` is not present. However, perhaps making now `limit` to be required would be a breaking change? Still I am not the one who decides :))

Comment: Yeah, true, but we could add a default-silent deprecation warning.